# Should I store a small picture avatar inside ClaimsIdentity in ASP.NET core? if not, what is the best way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET core and I am developing a website (.NET core 2.1) with user login.

I would like to be able to show an user avatar image in all pages that uses _Layout.cshtml.
So inside that file, for the user name I am already using: `@User.Identity.Name`.
Now I would like to use something like this: `@User.Claims.First("avatar")`

I am using Cookies based authentication:

In my "Startup.cs":

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    // support for cookie based authentication
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options => {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
        });
}
```

In my "AccountController":

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel m) {
    var user = Authenticate(m.Email, m.Password); // returns null when authentication fails
    if (user!=null) {
        var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
            new List<Claim> {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Company.Name),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email)
            }, "login");
        ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);
        return Redirect("/"); // redirect after authentication
    }
    return View("Login"); // default view if cannot authenticate
}
```

The avatar picture itself will be store in a firebase database, so I need to avoid database query for each page request of my website.

Since "claims" are used for authorization rules, I don't feel like I should use that to store a "small" byte array that I can use to render a JPG picture. Since I am showing it in every page during the user session, I want to load the picture to the server RAM during the Login and make it stay there for as long as the user remains logged-in.

I've found many examples where people will extend the class ClaimsPrincipal to add new properties, but that requires some other code change (seems to be related with IdentityModel using the entity framework) and a factory for ClaimsPrincipal objects. (If I have to take that direction, I would like a small example starting from the code I provided)

Remembering that I am new to ASP.NET core MVC...
If someone could point me towards a good direction I would appreciate.

Comment: You got an answer that appears to suggest both of the techniques you said you want to avoid. *"I want to load the picture to the server RAM"* - you've already identified a solution. Your question should be just about that (but take a look at [DistributedMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed), first).

Comment: Well I identified that I need to store in the RAM somehow. As far as I see, the Claims are stored in the RAM, so I would like to go with that. However I am not sure if I should use that mechanism to store the image bytes... (Before I give up and use a URL in the claims then retrieve the image from the disk, I was wondering if you guys have better suggestion).  Your cache suggestion seems interesting, and indeed answers a lot of other questions in my head... but for this particular case may be like using a baseball bat to kill a fly.

Comment: I believe Claims are included in the auth cookie (or maybe a separate one) so that it doesn't have to rely on the Session object (which is not available by default in ASP.NET Core).

Comment: hmm yeah you might be right about that... it could go with the cookie... wouldn't be that bad though... just won't stay in the RAM indeed. But I can live with that. That is the path I tried actually but could not integrate in my code above.

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom claims like that:

```
new Claim("Avatar", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
```

Since they only accept strings, you should convert your byte array into a base64 string.

However, I believe that the best way to do that is to have some sort of Storage, and then save only the URL of the picture in the database (and in the claims).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why the avatar only is shown when the user is online. Does only the user itself see his avatar?

But I am also currently working on the identity stuff for my project and maybe this solution works for you too.

I have a little controller logic for images underlying. All images are in a database and get served by a special MediaController. I also cache them on a folder, but that's a different story. This MediaController serves all images, identified by its id. The route is /media/images/{imageId:int}

This would work also with a filename instead of an id. Why handle a profile pic different from all other images?

My IdentityUser Class looks like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace MyProject.Identity
{
    public class MyProjectIdentity : IdentityUser<string>
    {
        //other properties...

        public int ProfilePicId { get; set; }

        //more other properties...
    }
}
```

On every view, where I show the Avatar I just do:

```
<img src="~/media/images/@User.ProfilePicId" alt="Profile Pic" />
```

Comment: the avatar there is just for himself. When someone access his profile page, I will do as you say, and request the picture from a DB. But now I have a website with a navigation menu, where in the top he got a tiny picture. That menu is delivered with every page request, this is why I don't want to rely in databases. I would have at least 1 request for each page. But in all other cases, I would treat as any other image. About your IdentityUser<> extension, I am missing how I should integrate the extended class MyProjectIdentity in my code.

Comment: That's why I have all images cached in a folder and handle them just like images. I do a lot of DB queries with every view, but the images only if they are not in the cache folder. The MyProjectIdentity inherits from IdentityUser and is used at *services.AddIdentity<MyProjectIdentity, MyProjectRole>()*... in startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

Its best to store avatar in DB, that way it is faster to load.

Refer this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1#storage-scenarios